# There is a way to add a column with the test statistics in gtsummary::tbl_regression()?

Tags: gtsummary

Is there a way to add the Statistic for each variable as a column in a `tbl_regresion()` with {gtsummary}? In Psychology is not uncommon for reviewers to expect this column in the tables.

When using {sjPlot}, just need to add the `show.stat` parameter, and the **Statistic** column will appear showing the `t value` from `summary(model)`.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(sjPlot)
  
model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + wt, data = mtcars)  
tab_model(model, show.stat = TRUE)
```

[image]

With {gtsummary} I can't find anywhere how to add an equivalent column when using tbl_regression(). Would just want to show a column with the values already present in the model.

```
library(gtsummary)      
model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + wt, data = mtcars)
  
stats_to_include =c("r.squared", "adj.r.squared", "nobs")
tbl_regression(model, intercept = TRUE, show_single_row = everything()) %>% 
  bold_p() %>% 
  add_glance_table(include = all_of(stats_to_include))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! The statistic column is already in the table, but it's hidden by default. You can unhide it (and other columns) with the `modify_column_unhide()` function. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary) 
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2'

model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + wt, data = mtcars)

tbl <-
  tbl_regression(model, intercept = TRUE, show_single_row = everything()) %>% 
  bold_p() %>% 
  add_glance_table(include = c(r.squared, adj.r.squared, nobs)) %>%
  modify_column_unhide(columns = c(statistic, std.error))
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

FYI if you're interested, we also support journal themes in gtsummary. You can, for example, load the JAMA theme and the gtsummary results will be auto-formatted for publication in JAMA. We don't have Psychology theme, but if you file a GitHub Issue, we can collaborate on adding one. We can add things like showing the statistic column by default (and much more).

https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/theme_gtsummary.html

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Would be awesome to have a "Psychology" theme, although I am not sure whether I can speak for the whole field :) Will play with the functionality and fill an Issue if I come up with something reasonable.

Comment: We can pick a top journal in the field and model the theme after their reporting guidelines